# Handy Etui – Zusammen? Bindestrich?

Tags: noun, spelling, compound

Wäre es ganz falsch, wenn ich es wie ein Kompositum zusammen schreiben würde → *Handyetui*?

Comment: Es gibt diesbezüglich sogar den (allerdings umstrittenen) Begriff [Deppenleerzeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diese Schreibweise ist falsch:

> *Handy Etui*

Manche Leute nennen das Leerzeichen in solchen Komposita gerne abwertend ein »Deppenleerzeichen«. So etwas gibt es in anderen Sprachen (z.B. im Englischen), aber nicht im Deutschen.

Diese beiden Formen sind hingegen beide erlaubt:

> Handy-Etui
>   Handyetui

Dabei gilt: Generell ist die Schreibweise ohne Bindestich vorzuziehen. Die Variante mit Bindestrich sollte man dann wählen, wenn das Wort ohne Bindestrich schwer lesbar ist, oder wenn es ohne Bindestrich missverstanden werden könnte:

> Der Bäcker stellte Fladen her, die besonders schwer zu kauen waren.
>   Er nannte sie **Kaufladen** und verkaufte sie im **Kaufladen.**
>   Er nannte sie **Kau-Fladen** und verkaufte sie im **Kauf-Laden.**

Ob das ganze Wort ein Substantiv ist oder nicht, hängt vom hinteren Wort ab. Davon hängt ab, ob man das ganze Kompositum groß- oder kleinschreibt:

> Dieter war zwar **bettelarm,** hatte aber trotzdem einen **Tennisarm.**
>   Dieter war zwar **bettel-arm,** hatte aber trotzdem einen **Tennis-Arm.**

Wenn man die Schreibung mit Bindestrich verwendet, schreibt man die Teile, die nicht am Anfang des Wortes stehen, so, wie man sie auch alleinstehend schreiben würde:

> Links-rechts-Kombination
>   Berg-und-Tal-Bahn
>   Oben-ohne-Lokal
>   Mund-zu-Mund-Beatmung

Comment: vielen Dank für die Antwort! noch eine kurze Frage: gilt das Wort "Konjunktivverbformen" als schwer lesbar? Sollte man es lieber mit Bindestrich schreiben? "Konjunktiv-Verbformen"?

Comment: @Serena: Das hängt sehr davon ab, wie du deine Leser einschätzt. Als Vielleser habe damit kein Problem, ich kann auch Wörter wie *Dichlordiphenyltrichlorethan* oder *Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz* einigermaßen gut lesen, während ich das z.B. von einen Siebenjährigen nicht erwarten würde.

Comment: @Serena. Ich persönlich hatte erhebliche Schwierigkeiten, deine *Konjunktivverbformen* zu lesen, weil die beiden v zu einem w verschmelzen. Ich wäre dir in diesem Fall aus lesepraktischer Sicht für Konjunktiv-Verbformen dankbar gewesen.

Comment: Christian: bin mit Dir bezüglich der verschmolzenen vv's einverstanden! für mich sieht die Version mit Bindestrich auch freundlicher aus... die Sache ist nur die, dass dieses Wort in einer (Uni-)Hausarbeit (über den Konjunktiv) mehrmals vorkommt und der Prüfer ist mit diesem Begriff vertraut. Wenn man das berücksichtigt, glaubt Ihr, sollte man lieber die zusammengeschriebene Version verwenden?

Answer (score 2):

Richtig: Handy-Etui

Richtig (aber etwas schwerer zu lesen): Handyetui

Falsch: Handy Etui, Handy etui, HandyEtui

Comment: Wenn du jetzt noch schreiben würdest, warum, dann wäre das eine Antwort.

Comment: Ich hab leider gerade keinen Duden da, aber so sind die Regeln. Die beiden Nomen sollen (gedanklich) zu einem Wort verbunden werden, und im Deutschen ist man (im Gegensatz zum Englischen) dazu verpflichtet, sie dann auch tatsächlich zu verbinden (entweder durch Zusammenschreibung oder durch einen Bindestrich).

Comment: "Warum"-Fragen im Kontext sprachlicher Gegebenheiten sind so eine Sache... manchmal reichte es fasst zu sagen "Es ist halt so", bzw. "So hat sich das halt festgesetzt".

Comment: Ja, durchaus. Aber ich glaube, er wollte eher darauf hinaus, dass ich allgemein ruhig ein bisschen mehr dazu hätte schreiben können. Da aber bereits wenige Minuten später eine wesentlich detailliertere Antwort gefolgt ist, spar ich mir mal die Mühe (kann ja ohnehin nur eine akzeptiert werden und ich wüsste nicht, was ich noch zu der anderen hinzufügen sollte).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "Warum"-Fragen, die der Rechtschreibrat schon mit einem eigenen (§45) Paragraphen in den Rechtschreibregeln beglückt hat, lassen sich sehr einfach mit diesem Paragraphen beantworten.

Comment: Annatar, ich danke Dir herzlich für Deine Antwort! : )

Comment: @tofro: Das sehe ich nicht so. Denn die Frage, **warum** der Rechtschreibrat diese Regel so und nicht anderes formuliert hat, bleibt unbeantwortet. Dieser Rat setzt die Regeln ja nicht willkürlich fest, sondern gibt in der Regel nur wieder, was die Mehrheit der Schreiber auch ohne den Rat tun würde. Die eigentliche Frage lautet fast immer: *»**Warum** hat dieser bestimmte Aspekt der Sprache ausgerechnet diese konkrete Ausprägung angenommen und keine andere?«* ...

Comment: ... Und die richtige Antwort darauf lautet sehr oft: *»Das ist eben rein zufällig so passiert und hätte genauso gut auch anders kommen können. Beispiele aus anderen Sprachen zeigen nämlich, dass es dort tatsächlich anders gekommen ist.«*